# Use reCaptcha in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, recaptcha

I'm looking for solution how to integrate WPF desktop application with reCaptcha! Anyone knows the solution?

I'm working on registration module to my application, and need good and simple captcha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display and https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify.

You could make an request to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key and parse the ChallengeValue. This value can be used to get the recaptcha image via http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=challenge_value. Afaik URL Images can be displayed in WPF directly.

Let the user input into a TextBox (or similar) control.

For verification, use this input and make a request to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify (see documentation above).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this - http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html.  It says it works in any .Net language, including C#.  There is also [this page](http://cplus.about.com/b/2008/09/29/recaptcha-killing-two-birds-with-one-stone.htm) although it is 2 years old.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I saw that solution. I don't think it's suitable for me. I have desktop app in WPF and C#, where I need to implement registration with recaptcha. Don't know how to use asp control in my case. :)

Comment: I think that API is open source, you could possibly extract the wrappers and place in a WPF control instead?  I haven't seen anything else similar though :(