# Requesting a recaptcha and caching the image

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, captcha, recaptcha

I need to create a WCF application that requests a "recaptcha" and sends it over to a WCF client, as a **bitmap**. All examples I have found so far are built to display the captcha in a web browser, wheras I need the actual recaptcha image.

The reaason I need to do this is because I need to create a registration screen in a c# WinForms application. Here's how it works:

1. User opens registration screen through windows application.
2. Application requests a captcha from WCF server.
3. WCF server generates and sends captcha.
4. Application displays captcha and allows user to enter details.
5. Application sends details and captcha code to server via WCF.
6. Server sends return code (ie: If registration was successful or if it failed.)

Note that a hosted website is not an option at this point. There is only a WCF server and a WCF client. I have been trying to avoid generating my own captcha and using re-captcha instead, but I have not managed to find a way to download the actual captcha image. Any alternative solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12154911/518923

As the answer suggests, use http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key to get the challenge, parse ChallengeValue, then you can get the image via http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=challenge_value

Afterwards you can verify the challenge via http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify
Make sure to check the documentation on the subject https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Shamelessly copied from the linked post, but I will take no credit ;)

Comment: Thanks! I searched but I could not find that thread. I didn't use the right keywords.