# How to Create Stripped background in WPF, using Gradients

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styling, wpf-4.0

I need to create a stripped background for a border which should look like this...

[image]

I tried following code its working as back ground,but when i try to use in inside a data template its displaying grey background instead of stripped.

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
   <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"/>
   <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
   <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Black"/>
   <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Black"/>
   <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
   </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: 0.01 seems a very important scale for a control.

Comment: Another rq : You could use an imageBrush as background.

Comment: Are you trying to [create a captcha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963833/use-recaptcha-in-wpf-app)?

Comment: Show us the datatemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale factor is based on percentage values.  Let's say that you apply the brush to a Rectangle Width = 600, Height=600, then with a scaleX = 0.01 a stripe is ~6 pixels in width.  But shrink the Rectangle size to Width=60, Height=60, and the stripe is  ~0.6 pixels wide. With such small stripes, the background will look gray.

Since you didn't show your DataTemplate I can't tell what size your elements are.

If this is your issue, then use a binding to change the ScaleX,ScaleY values based on the size of the target element.

Comment: Hi Walt Ritscher,

I am using a Border of size 40X40 i have changed scaleX and Scale y value and also changed End point details.. it worked thanks