# How can i load a reCaptcha from a different website in XAML/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, recaptcha

I'm working in a system that download documents from a governmental website for our clients. This site use captcha and we provide two option for them: use API like AntiCaptcha to automatically bypass the captcha's, or, break the captcha themselves. 
Until recently that site use captcha images and everything was working just fine, but now they update to reCaptcha and we can't make it the application load the reCaptcha for the client.

The form that presents the reCaptcha in our application is written in WPF/XAML.

The site in question is [this](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=).

It is possible to do that?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963833/use-recaptcha-in-wpf-app       but trying to re-implement that by your own will be a real pain.

Comment: Yes, i see that answer, but doesn't work for me because i don't wanna implement a reCaptcha from our website. I need to implement the reCaptcha that's been displayed in this site: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consultaRecaptcha.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, i use cefSharp to load the page that I need and javascript injection in cefSharp to remove all the elements and leave just the reCaptcha visible.

To capture the response of reCaptcha i use asynchronous javascript with cefSharp to "listen" the field 'g-recaptcha-response', when is different then empty, i save in a variable and proceed with the implementation.